# Flutter, GetX initState

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

can someone explain how to use `onInit` in `GetX` and is it important to use the `dispose`/`onClose` ?

i want to `GET` api data and show it from the start of the app

already googled it didn't find anything helpful :(

Comment: why ? something's wrong with getx? im new know nothing what good or bad with state management

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class ShoppingController extends GetxController {
  List<ProductModel> products = <ProductModel>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    getData();
  }

  Future<List<ProductModel>> getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products').get();
    products = querySnapshot.docs
        .map((m) => ProductModel.fromJson(m.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
    return products;
  }
}
```

Comment: do i need to use the onClose too?

Comment: exactly not this. but find solution if controller any data build during setState or you call initState() function. then this variable or data you assign getX controller onInit() funciton.